# Looking for PCIe tv-tuner card for OTA/ATSC and dual tuners that works with mythubuntu (16.04)

Tags: tv-tuner

I live in Ohio, and use OTA so it has to be ATSC.  I have given up on  trying to get the Hauppauge WinTV-QuadHD (for ATSC) to work.  Does anyone know for sure what card really works?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware recommendations are off topic. Please ask on [HardwareRecs.SE] instead.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the SiliconDust HDHomeRun networked tuners work with MythTV.

I run two such tuners. An older DUAL which allows two separate coax inputs, and a PRIME which allows cablecard use for encrypted/premium channels.

Comment: Thanks. i have researched that option, but it is not the right fit for me.  I'm looking for a PCIe card.

Comment: I'd edit that into your question. I don't think that you'll be able to find one.

Comment: I'm just trying to find a "tried & true" PCIe tv-tuner card that will work with Ubuntu 16.04 (or 16.10), preferably with dual tuners.  There has to be one out there that works.

Comment: Add all those requirements to your question.